# Make picture one size unsizible or something

Tags: css

Hello stackoverflow people, I need help. I don't know how to make that when window resizes (making responsive website) these both lines, the part where they are windy would be same big as they are.
[image]

Because when I do this:

```
                <div class="titul_caption">
                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/forthecause/images/elemo1.png">
                    <p><?php  echo $temos_set['titul_text']; ?></p> 
                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/forthecause/images/emelo12.png">          
                </div>
```

And resizing window, they just getting smaller and smaller..
So is there are any way to make them stay big but shorter? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By its nature "responsive" means to respond to the window or viewport size or type, so elements would change size or style depending on how you create the code.

The meta-tag: viewport achieves this option:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If you do not want the elements to resize when the window/viewport changes, you need to be explicit in the css or style. For instance setting:

```
 min-width: 200px; max-width:200px;
```

Will force the element to remain at 200px. But if you are going to do that, there's no need, IMHO, to use the viewport meta-tag. The style will respond according to the parameters you provide in the css, in which case, you'll need to think about each version of your stylesheet for each type of device (iPad, Android smartphone, widescreen iMac, etc).